# Unit Test Coverage is not showing in JetBrains Rider 2022.2.3 Mac version

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin, code-coverage, jetbrains-rider

Not able to see Unit test case coverage in Rider in Mac although DotCover and DotTrace plug in's are enable.

[image]

Comment: Does it work in Visual Studio or for other projects?

Comment: No it is not working

Comment: Then you've probably misconfigured your coverage settings. Depending on your platform (xUnit, NUnit, etc.) and version, make sure that all necessary packages are available

Comment: @mu88 I am also having this issue. 
I'm using xunit. The coverage was working last week and suddenly stopped. Any idea what settings you would be referring to that could cause this?

Comment: And do you have access to a Windows machine where you can give it a try?

Comment: I downloaded Rider 2022.3 EAP 7 and it's working in there. Something must just be broken in 2022.2.3.

Comment: Update: I uninstalled EAP 7, reinstalled 2022.2.3 and it seems to work again. There must be some sort of hiccup with the process. @NikhilNandha I suggest you try uninstalling and reinstalling.